# cannot find class for bean with name defined in servletcontext resource

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

16:29:46,134 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Context initialization failed:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.americanexpress.bip.app.util.BIPPropertyLoader] for bean with name 'com.americanexpress.bip.app.util.BIPPropertyLoader#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/spring-property-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.americanexpress.bip.app.util.BIPPropertyLoader from [Module "deployment.BIPAdminWeb.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1008/1206637670.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1009/435941282.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1009/435941282.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1009/435941282.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1501)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1009/435941282.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.americanexpress.bip.app.util.BIPPropertyLoader from [Module "deployment.BIPAdminWeb.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: please ensure that jar containing `com.americanexpress.bip.app.util.BIPPropertyLoader` class is bundled in your war

Comment: yeah it is there. i am trying to migrate my project from jboss 6.4 to 7.1.0 and thats when am facing this issue. the code is working fine with jboss 6